# VBA Excel: Argument not optional

Tags: vba, excel, userform, listboxitems

Very new to vba and I'm having some issues with a piece of code. In essence, I'm trying to perform different worksheet functions on user selected items from a list box in a user form.

```
Private Sub cmdRunStat_Click()
Dim averageValue As Single
Dim sdValue As Single
Dim maxValue As Variant
Dim minValue As Single
Dim modeValue As Single
Dim UserRange As String, sheetName As String


Set UserRange = ListBox1.Selected = True


If optAverage.Value = True Then

  averageValue = WorksheetFunction.Average(UserRange)
  MsgBox "The average of the selected data is " & averageValue

ElseIf optSD.Value = True Then

   sdValue = WorksheetFunction.StDev(UserRange)
   MsgBox "The standard deviation of the selected data is " & sdValue

ElseIf optMax.Value = True Then

   maxValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(UserRange)
   MsgBox "The maximum of the slected data is " & maxValue

ElseIf optMin.Value = True Then

   minValue = WorksheetFunction.Min(UserRange)
   MsgBox "The minimum of the slected data is " & minValue

Else

    modeValue = WorksheetFunction.Mode(UserRange)
    MsgBox "The mode of the slected data is " & modeValue

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the compiler error isn't "Object required" on the line `Set UserRange = ListBox1.Selected = True`?

Comment: you can't `Set` value to string . this is wrong `Set UserRange = ListBox1.Selected = True`

Comment: If you are using a ListBox to enter a string that represents a range, then you need to use `Set UserRange = ListBox1.Value` , just remember that string need to contain a format like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D10")`

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3):

> Set UserRange = ListBox1.Selected = True

That is an incorrect way to assign to a `String` Object.

If you are trying to get the selected value from the listbox then I think this is what you need?

```
Dim UserRange As String

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        UserRange = ListBox1.List(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

And if it is a `Range` Object then you need to change the above as

```
Dim UserRange As Range

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        Set UserRange = ListBox1.List(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll make those changes.